# Leaflet and tiler for R - can't get the correct tiles for displaying in Leaflet (wrong reference systeme or something)

Tags: raster, r, leaflet, tiles

I have got an issue with tiler (https://github.com/ropensci/tiler). I am setting up a webapplication and want to convert .grd files to tiles that can be read by Leaflet.

This example can be easily follow by using the files and putting them under a folder called /data, as you can see in the code, that is needed.

[You can download the used files here at Gofile](https://gofile.io/d/hyWDHA)

I had to set the routes with tiler_options because there where some errors with systemvariables and the paths. But it runs and there is a output. But the tiles are obviously not in the right reference system.
This is my code (remember to install and load the package):

```
tiler_options(osgeo4w = "C:/OSGeo4W64/OSGeo4W.bat", python="C:/Users/____/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe")

tile(file= 'data/aoa_result_2.grd',
     tiles= 'layers/aoa_result',
     zoom="10-13",
     viewer= TRUE,
)
```

Even the passed viewer can't display the layer correctly. The XML file shows that the EPSG is 3857 but I guess that is not right for leaflet. It should be EPSG:4326 instead i guess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://tms.osgeo.org/1.0.0">
      <Title>tmp_raster.tif</Title>
      <Abstract></Abstract>
      <SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
      <BoundingBox minx="7.40000709521776" miny="51.85465878258405" maxx="7.82132047624863" maxy="52.06491340494047"/>
      <Origin x="7.40000709521776" y="51.85465878258405"/>
      <TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png"/>
      <TileSets profile="mercator">
        <TileSet href="10" units-per-pixel="152.87405654296876" order="10"/>
        <TileSet href="11" units-per-pixel="76.43702827148438" order="11"/>
        <TileSet href="12" units-per-pixel="38.21851413574219" order="12"/>
        <TileSet href="13" units-per-pixel="19.10925706787109" order="13"/>
      </TileSets>
    </TileMap>
```

I tried some reprojections but always got the same refsys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just watch out for TMS-Tiles. tiler does export TMS-Tiles but even the viewer seems to be unprepared for that.
I used leaflet-react and set the tms property with value "true" and it worked:

```
      <TileLayer
    attribution="&copy;  contributors"
    url={
      "/static/layers/" +
      currentProject.projectname +
      "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    }
    tms="true"
    minZoom="10"
    maxZoom="18"
  />
```